# Android - Firebase Error: Discarding data. Failed to send app launch

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to retrieve data from Firebase database to my recycler view and I keep getting this error no matter what I try. How can I solve this issue?

In my emulator Google Play Service version is: 11.5.80
I have no physical Android device so I didn't test on a real device.
I tried to update my emulator but there was no update available for emulator.

```
Discarding data. Failed to send app launch
Failed to get app instance id
Failed to send current screen to service
Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
```

Also Logcat says `Google Play services out of date`.

```
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x912a2040, tid 8449
01-15 07:36:02.928 8422-8449/com.user.myapp I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
01-15 07:36:02.928 8422-8449/com.user.myapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-15 07:36:02.929 8422-8449/com.user.myapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
01-15 07:36:02.929 8422-8449/com.user.myapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
01-15 07:36:02.929 8422-8449/com.user.myapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
01-15 07:36:02.934 8422-8449/com.user.myapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa10843c0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
01-15 07:36:02.949 8422-8449/com.user.myapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa10843c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa1083630)
01-15 07:36:02.952 8422-8449/com.user.myapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
01-15 07:36:02.952 8422-8449/com.user.myapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
01-15 07:36:02.952 8422-8449/com.user.myapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
01-15 07:36:02.953 8422-8449/com.user.myapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
01-15 07:36:03.024 8422-8449/com.user.myapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa10843c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa1083630)
01-15 07:36:03.061 8422-8451/com.user.myapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
01-15 07:36:03.155 8422-8443/com.user.myapp V/FA: Connecting to remote service
01-15 07:36:03.191 8422-8443/com.user.myapp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11910000 but found 11580470
01-15 07:36:03.195 8422-8422/com.user.myapp W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
01-15 07:36:03.230 8422-8443/com.user.myapp V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
01-15 07:36:03.230 8422-8443/com.user.myapp E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send app launch
01-15 07:36:03.230 8422-8443/com.user.myapp E/FA: Failed to get app instance id
01-15 07:36:03.230 8422-8443/com.user.myapp E/FA: Failed to send current screen to service
01-15 07:36:03.230 8422-8443/com.user.myapp E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
01-15 07:36:03.231 8422-8443/com.user.myapp V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 0
```

Here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.user.myapp”
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    // firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I got this error when `google play service` was not up to date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run using an API 27 emulator image.  There is currently (14 Jan) no released API 27 emulator image that support Firebase/Google Play version 11.8.0.

Your options are to run using an API 26 emulator image, or downgrade the library versions in your build:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
...
targetSdkVersion 26
...
// for all Support Libs, use 26.1.0
...
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
```

Comment: 18 Jul and it still only supporting API 26